# Sorting of database table by encrypted field

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, encryption

I have a SQLite table which looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  encrypted_field BLOB
);
```

in fact this BLOB is just AES-256 encrypted JSon of Java class like:

```
public class MySecretClass {
   private Date date;
   private String message;
}
```

Since, it's under Android - I have `ContentProvider` which reads data, decrypts record "on-fly" and feeds appropriate `ListView` or `RecyclerView`

I need to somehow provide sorting by `Date` and `String`

My first intention was to introduce additional field in my table such that it will reflects records modifications and somehow "emulate" sorting by `Date` and `String`, but in the end I stuck and found that it's infeasible.

Any other ideas, workarounds?

Comment: are you using a CursorAdapter ?

Comment: Why are you not using an encrypted database, like SQLCipher for Android? Then, you could write an ordinary SQL query for this, assuming that your date and message were in regular SQL columns.

Comment: 1) Yes, it's sort of `CursorAdapter`. 

2) Well, I can't use SQLCipher - it's long enough story and for sure beyound scopes of this post ))

Comment: Regardless of what "long story" prevents you from letting your db do the encryption, if something that isn't able to decrypt it is able to sort it - _you have a weakness in your encryption_. Even just storing sort order alongside the encrypted data undoes so much of your security effort that you should question why you're bothering to encrypt it in the first place. .... **Conclusion**: Sort in the application, not in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sort in the application, not in the database.

Yes, I agree it's best solution.

Specifically, I will use `MatrixCursor`, which is ideal for my purpoces. Decrypt content and put objects into `MatrixCursor` will give desired result.

Fortunately, sortable content is not huge, just few words per record with reasonable number of records (< 1000).